# What is initial mysql root password in zabbix_server_mysql?

Tags: mysql, zabbix, ubuntu-16.04

I followed the [instruction](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/installation/install_from_packages/server_installation_with_mysql) to install `zabbix_server_mysql 3.2` in `Ubuntu16`.

```
wget http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.2/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-release_3.2-1+xenial_all.deb
dpkg -i zabbix-release_3.2-1+xenial_all.deb
apt-get update
apt-get install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-frontend-php
```

After complete to install, I try to connect `mysql` for the next instruction like below.

```
Creating initial database

Create Zabbix database and user on MySQL by the following commands, where <root_password> shall be replaced with the actual root password (e.g., shell> mysql -uroot -p12345) and <password> with new password for zabbix user on the database (including apostrophes: …identified by '67890';):

shell> mysql -uroot -p<root_password>
mysql> create database zabbix character set utf8 collate utf8_bin;
mysql> grant all privileges on zabbix.* to zabbix@localhost identified by '<password>';
mysql> quit;
```

It is saying I need to type the actual root's password even though I have never set root password while installing `zabbix_server_mysql`.

At the first I tried to assume default password like empty string "", "root" and "zabbix" something.

Then I tried to change root password to what I want.

```
$sudo service mysql stop
$sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

# Another terminal
$mysql -uroot mysql
mysql > update user set password=PASSWORD("root") where User='root';
mysql > flush privileges;
mysql > quit;
$ sudo service mysql restart
$ mysql -uroot -proot
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Unfortunately, these seem not to work as I don't know why.

I have been stuck for quite long time, even not starting `zabbix` at all.

Could you give me an advice ?

## Edit -------------------------------------------------

```
dpkg -l | grep mysql
ii  libdbd-mysql-perl                     4.033-1ubuntu0.1                                            amd64        Perl5 database interface to the MySQL database
ii  libmysqlclient20:amd64                5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                                     amd64        MySQL database client library
ii  mysql-common                          5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                                     all          MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ii  php-mysql                             1:7.0+35ubuntu6                                             all          MySQL module for PHP [default]
ii  php7.0-mysql                          7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                                     amd64        MySQL module for PHP
ii  zabbix-server-mysql                   1:3.2.3-1+xenial                                            amd64        Zabbix network monitoring solution - server (MySQL)
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-version`? Replace "version" with something like 5.6.

Comment: @Khaled
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure` shows only `mysql-common` is available for `mysql` and it doesn't have any effect with `mysql-common`.

Comment: No `mysql-server` package!? How did you install mysql server?

Comment: @Khaled  
I didn't install `mysql` separately, it seems `zabbix_server_mysql` to install it together, that is why I am asking it on `server fault` if there is default password `zabbix_server_mysql` set for `root` user while installing it.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dpkg -l | grep mysql`?

Comment: @Khaled 
I edit my post adding result of `dpkg -l | grep mysql`.

Comment: No, there is not a default password; you set one explicitly when you install MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zabbix-mysql-server will install mysql (or mariadb) if it's not installed  yet on your system, as it is a dependency, but it will not provide a default root password.

Once your installation of mysql is done, try launching

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

and you'll be able to set the root password of your MySQL installation.

Only after this, you can follow the documentation to create the db, user, etc..

The Zabbix documentation, the way it is written, is assuming that your MySQL is already installed and properly configured. In your situation, it's not done.

Comment: `mysql_secure_installation` still ask me root password even though it is saying `If you've just installed MariaDB, and
you haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,
so you should just press enter here.` blank doesn't work.........

Comment: Because you've changed it, right ? 

If you want to do a "fresh" install and start over, try this :
  apt-get --yes purge mysql-server mysql-client && apt-get --yes autoremove --purge && apt-get autoclean then reinstall mysql-server and try again, you should be fine.

Comment: Is it now solved ?

Comment: Thank you for your attention but  It was still the same, finally I just installed `mysql` separately and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

After entering and conforming your password, you will receive the 3rd prompt with "Do you wish to continue with the password provided?(Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No)"

Press CTRL+C on following prompt and you will be exited from "mysql_secure_installation"

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this problem:
type *sudo -i* then type you root password. after that

```
# mysql -uroot -p
```

and enter you root system password. And its all :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The problem is that the root password is unknown.